# The Following Class could not be instantiated - android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat

Tags: android

I need to use `SwitchCompat` to support API<14. For this purpose i have added android.support.v7.appcompat.jar in my project. Under that i am able to see android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat.class. But when I am using

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

in my xml..getting rendering problem and Error like `"The Following Class could not be instantiated - android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat".`

Comment: Are you eclipse? In java code are you able to see SwitchCompat? In which android version are you running this?

Comment: Yes using Eclipse. I have added this as external lib. Able to see class file on Referenced library folder.